# Conjecture for a certain Cauchy-type determinant

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, determinants, matrix-theory, closed-form-expressions, q-analogs

Given the Cauchy-like matrix
$$
\mathbf X_M(q) = \left[ \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{
\Gamma\!\left(m - \frac{1}{2} \right)\Gamma\!\left(n + \frac{1}{2} \right)
}{
\Gamma(m)\,\Gamma(n)
}
\frac{m-\frac{3}{4}}
{\left(m-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2-\left(n-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2} q^{m+n-1} \right]_{m,n=1}^{M},
$$
show that for $M \to \infty$
$$
\det[\mathbf I_{\infty} + \mathbf X_{\infty}^T(q) \, \mathbf X_{\infty}(q)] = (q^2)_{\infty}^{-1/4} =
 \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{2k})^{1/4}},\qquad (1)
$$

with the Euler Gamma function $\Gamma(x)$ and the $q$-Pochhammer symbol $(q)_{\infty}$, while $\mathbf X^T$ denotes the transpose of $\mathbf X$. Note that this conjecture appeared in chapter 5.1 of [1], with $q = \exp(-\pi \rho)$, and I still have no idea how to prove it.

Motivated by a related question [259104](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259104) (see comments), I looked at similar determinant expressions for $\mathbf X_\infty(q)$, and by comparing the series expansions in $q$ found 
$$
\det[\mathbf I_{\infty} \pm \mathbf X_{\infty}(q)]
 = \det[\mathbf I_{\infty} \mp \mathbf X_{\infty}(-q)]
 = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1 \mp q^{2k-1})^{1/2}}{(1-q^{2k})^{1/8}}, \qquad(2)
$$
such that
$$
\det[\mathbf I_{\infty} - \mathbf X_{\infty}^2(q)]
 = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1 - q^{4k-2})^{1/2}}{(1-q^{2k})^{1/4}}
 = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{2k})^{(-1)^k/4}},\qquad(3)
$$
which is an alternating product version of (1).
Note the apparent similarity to (1) and (2) in [259104](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259104), which are the $k=1$ terms of our products. 
So the question is: How can one prove these identities?

See also related MathOverflow questions [199922](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199922) and [236323](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236323) and [259104](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259104).

[1] *Hucht, Alfred*, [**The square lattice Ising model on the rectangle. II: Finite-size scaling limit**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/aa6b7a), J. Phys. A, Math. Theor. 50, No. 26, Article ID 265205, 23 p. (2017). [ZBL1369.82005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1369.82005).

Comment: Related? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259104/a-neat-evaluation-of-an-infinite-matrix

Comment: @t-amdeberhan: Definitely related, I added more material above. Thanks for the reference!